# Where can I set CurrentUICulture in an ASP.NET web page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, globalization

I was reading a resource that said:

> `CurrentUICulture must be set at the startup of a application.`

For an ASP.NET web page, where do I set this property appropriately?

Comment: What document are you referring to?

Comment: If any of the given answers is correct, could you please mark it as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a web page, you can set Culture and UICulture in the page directive:

```
<%@ Page .... Culture="en-US" UICulture="en-US" %>
```

It doesn't have to be set at application startup.

**Update**: And as Kristof Claes mentions in a comment, you can set it in code during `Page_Init`:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Yes, preferably in the Page_Init():  
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

Answer (score 3):

Web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
  Page.Culture = "your culture";
  Page.UICulture = "your culture";
```

See [Page.UICulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture.aspx) and [Page.Culture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.culture.aspx)  on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

I do this, on the page itself

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
                   Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo(var.Sess.lang)
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```